# Double-underlining on linked questions on profile page

Tags: bug, design, style, hyperlinks, profile-page

If I hover over the upper edge of a question on [a profile page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/3794/energynumbers), then first one line appears under the hyperlink, and as I move the mouse down, towards the centre of the question, then as the mouse passed into the hyperlink box, the cursor changes, and a second line appears under the hyperlink:

[image]

That second underline shouldn't be there, should it?

Comment: Interestingly, in my browser, this occurs only for questions, not answers. But, it also happens for the bottom couple of entries in the reputation summary at right (but not the top two or three).

Comment: This is happening on Opera 12, Windows 7 as well

Comment: Hi EnergyNumbers! Are you still having this issue? If not (e.g. because this was some bug that was fixed since 2013) then maybe this Q can be deleted? I was about to get rid of the [style] tag on Meta but if this Q were to be deleted then there is no need to edit it :-)